# Governance Registry Database Cleaning

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

My GREG database (mysql) is growing up to 1.1 Million rows in the REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY and REG_PROPERTY tables.
I think it happens because the versioning is active.
Is there any way to do some kind of cleanup for the database ?

I want to maintain the last version and, if it is possible, to purge records older than a specified date.

Thanks for the help
Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY and REG_PROPERTY tables grow-up relatively due to resource revisioning when adding a Property. REG_SNAPSHOT, REG_RESOURCE_HISTORY and REG_CONTENT_HISTORY tables grow-up relatively due to resource revisioning when adding a new Resource.

Automatic revisioning on resource change can be disabled by changing the 
`<versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>` parameter in registry.xml

or else you can create a script to remove unwanted records from the db.
Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: You can manage version history by removing older versions from the UI with the new improvement https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-658 This is available in trunk now.

Comment: I'll wait for the new improvement. It is just what is was looking for.Thanks.